# Pass an empty value to Docker's build-args

Tags: python, python-3.x, docker, dockerfile

Let's suppose I have this python script *main.py*:

```
import sys
if not sys.argv[1]:
    print('Empty')
    sys.exit()
print('Otherwise')
```

If I run it like this *python3 main.py ''*, it prints **Empty**

If I run it like this *python3 main.py 45*, it prints **Otherwise**

Now let's say I'm going to build a Docker image that runs this script. This is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.6-slim
ARG A_VARIABLE

WORKDIR /
COPY main.py /

RUN python3 main.py ${A_VARIABLE}
```

If I build my image using this command **docker build --build-arg A_VARIABLE=45 .** it's working fine.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.905MB
Step 1/5 : FROM python:3.6-slim
 ---> c36a97a24d09
Step 2/5 : ARG A_VARIABLE
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9146c21f196
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 942a7511c60d
Step 4/5 : COPY main.py /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 96bd3882233a
Step 5/5 : RUN python3 main.py ${A_VARIABLE}
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 4c9f0b1b997c
Successfully built 4c9f0b1b997c
```

If I build it like this **docker build --build-arg A_VARIABLE='' .** it fails.

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  1.905MB
Step 1/5 : FROM python:3.6-slim
 ---> c36a97a24d09
Step 2/5 : ARG A_VARIABLE
 ---> Using cache
 ---> e9146c21f196
Step 3/5 : WORKDIR /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 942a7511c60d
Step 4/5 : COPY main.py /
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 96bd3882233a
Step 5/5 : RUN python3 main.py ${A_VARIABLE}
 ---> Running in e1b5dab971d2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    if not sys.argv[1]:
IndexError: list index out of range
The command '/bin/sh -c python3 main.py ${A_VARIABLE}' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Is there any workaround for this so that I can pass empty values as build-args?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the shell (and thus in a Dockerfile `RUN` statement) an unquoted empty variable simply disappears.

```
RUN python3 main.py "${A_VARIABLE}"
```

See also [When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10067266/when-to-wrap-quotes-around-a-shell-variable)

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    print('Empty')
    sys.exit()
print('Otherwise')
```

In python code instead of using argv[1], check the length of array of command line arguments passed.
That way, you can pass empty arguments in docker command.